# Can I restore backup in WhatsApp from first Gmail account when currently my data is being backup in the other?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

All my data was backed up in my Google account, then I login WhatsApp in my other mobile and backed up next data in other second gmail account. Is there any way way to restore data from first account too?

Answer (score 1):

Normally WhatsApp makes local backups too. I assume when you say other mobile you are using WhatsApp on a second phone, so on the first phone you might be able to open WhatsApp and go to settings, backup and tap make a backup now. It should make a local backup to your internal storage or sdcard if you have one under a folder named WhatsApp. The backups are encrypted so you can't just modify them. The key is stored in the app data. There is information on how to merge WhatsApp databases on [XDA forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-merge-multiple-whatsapp-backup-file-into-one-no-root-required.3142974/) but it requires root.